# Unable to create a Collection in Firestore - request blocked:mixed-content

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-console

I've been trying to create a new collection at https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/data?project={PROJECT} however when I do, nothing happens. Opening the dev tools and looking at the Networking tab shows the requests are not going through (see screenshot). I'm using Chrome 83.0.4103.97 on OSX 10.15.4 (19E287). I have tried to go to Site Settings and change unsafe content to Allow, however that did not make a difference.

Anybody got any idea how I could make it work?

[image: Screenshot of Networking tab]

Comment: If you click on one of the error, what is the complete body of the response? My first thought is to try in an incognito window, disable all add-ons/extensions for your browser, or try in a different browser.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen there is no response, since the request is blocked. Incognito worked, and from that found that it was the "Disconnect" extension that was blocking these requests. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that you found it Alice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alice and @Frank resolved it however I think this is worth creating an answer.

In such situation first thing to check if incognito window is behaving the same way. There might be some extension that are blocking request.

In this situation there was "Disconnect" extension which was blocking.

I hope it will help someone in future!